# Sending mails not working in production environment - same settings

Tags: asp.net, email, iis, web-config, smtp

On my website i send e-mails. My situation is these mails are being sent when using my local development machine, and not on my production environment.

The web.config is the same on both sites:

```
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="info@domain.dk" deliveryMethod="Network">
        <network host="mail.domain.dk" userName="info@domain.dk"  password="mypassword" port="26"></network>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

In my code, I send it like this:

```
 SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
 client.Send(mail);
```

I have no idea how to debug this problem, as it is the exactly same code on both production and development.

Any ideas on how to start debugging / solving the problem?

EDIT:

I managed to get a log from the server. Error is:

```
2012-11-01 20:41:58,383 [11] FATAL GKBusiness.Managers.MailManager [(null)] - Email exception: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: Access denied - Invalid HELO name (See RFC2821 4.1.1.1)
```

Hmm

Comment: Does mail.domain.dk allow relaying from the IP address of your server? Some mail services might have restrictions in place.

Comment: I currently don't know - I've asked my hosting provider.. But I am pretty sure that's not the cause, as the server is one of theirs

Comment: try adding `client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;` It might help.

Comment: Not working.. It seems that the server is totally rejected - no matter what login I provided it gives the same error. It's strange - I can ping the mail-server but logging in gives me the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My situation is these mails are being sent when using my **local** development machine, and *not* on my **production** environment.

```
<network host=..... port="26">
```

**If** you are in a *shared hosting environment*, it's likely that ASP.Net is set to `Medium Trust` - and if so, [SMTP is restricted to **port 25**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alvar/archive/2010/02/08/smtp-problems-when-asp-net-is-not-running-in-full-trust.aspx).

It will work in your **local** environment because ASP.Net is set to `Full Trust` (in local/VS dev).

Comment: It doesn't work even though I've set full trust on the website, unfortunately.. :-(

Comment: @Mcoroklo Unclear if you have full control of your (production) server. If you don't (shared hosting), you **can't** "override" the **machine config** (set by your hosting provider) in your web site/app's web.config.

Comment: I have full control :-) It's a VPS